# ASP.NET Data Source

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to give in the "Data Source" link the path of my Database (code below) but it always take the path with "C:\Windows" at the beginning so i have this error : "Ensure that the path name is correct."

```
SelectStatement_24 = "Select * From Users Where User_ID=" & User_Num
ConnectString_24 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=..\Applis\gestion_actions.mdb"
Connect_24.ConnectionString = ConnectString_24
Adapter_24.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(SelectStatement_24,Connect_24)
Adapter_24.Fill(ClassyDS_24,"Utilisateur_Info")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your connection string to below

```
 ConnectString_24= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/") & "//Applis//gestion_actions.mdb"
```